# Asp.net 2 buttons return same page with different data

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my Ascx page ive got 2 buttons, those buttons redirect to same page atm. (because page should be exactly same). In Page_Load() method sender parameter doesnt have any parameters. How do i tell Page_Load event which button was clicked? so i can load different data depends on which button was clicked?

Are there any way to do it more dynamicly? or do i have to create a separate page for each button?

Comment: pass queryString and make a difference.

Comment: query string already contains a guid, but i will create a separate page, was just hoping for i could get around it some how

Comment: can't you pass two value in queryString: Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?guid=1&btn=2");

Comment: oh... didn know that you can have more the one parameter in queryString, thanks alot!

Comment: @Timsen Ashwini is right , you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what you trying to do , this could be silly but still you can achieve this by doing something like this

```
Button1_Click
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?id=1")

Button2_Click
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?id=2")
```

Then on the load event

```
if(Request.QueryString["id"]==1)
button1
else
button2
```

You can also multiple parameters to a page like this

```
 Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?id=1&name=xyz")
```

And retrieve it

```
Request.QueryString["name"]=="xyz"
```

Comment: well then i can add a new page as well :P

Comment: @Timsen what exactly you want , the solution I provided is not suitable for you is it?

Comment: @Timsen creating different pages will be a better solution

Comment: @Timsen I edited my answer , you can pass multiple parameter to a page if you want

Answer (score 1):

The postback event for the button click is called right **after** the Page_Load, there you can tell which button was clicked and then do some stuff on the OnPreRender method

Or maybe I have misunderstood and you redirect to another page. In this case, I'm with Ashwini Verma, add some query string or pass some var through Session. The choice is yours